# How to get rid of mosquitoes without electricity?

Tags: home, comfort, pest-control

In the summer we used to start fans or cooler while sleeping, but sometimes due to some technical issues at night we have no electricity, so our fans and cooler stop working at that time.

I am focusing on this because due to velocity of air which comes through these fans, they protect me from mosquitoes. But when fans and cooler stop working, then at many mosquitoes come to my face and start biting me. Sometimes it's quite irritating, making me unable to sleep.

I really don't want to use mosquito coil as it really smokes a lot which makes me unable to breathe. And if it comes to using a net, then its really hard to build inside my room. And since there is no electricity I can't even use any gadget to kill.

So is there any way that I can use to get rid of all these mosquitoes which bite me at night while in absence of electricity?

Comment: Stupid question: if you are in a closed room, why don't just put screens in the windows ? Make sure mosquito don't come into the house in the first place.

Comment: It won't fit as an answer since you want a self-working solution, but this IMO is by far the best tool to manually get rid of mosquitoes: https://ilcorsivoquotidiano.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/racchettainsetti6.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Citronella is a natural repellent.  It can be used to discourage mosquitoes.

Although it is available in the form of scented candles, I'd rather not burn these while I'm sleeping. I just use them in the evening.

Citronella is available as an Essential Oil from aromatherapy shops.  Put just a few drops of this into some water, then dampen around the edge of the bed with it.  It is not necessary to use the oil in its concentrated form, it works better diluted and distributed.

It isn't 100% effective but it comes close.

Comment: +1, though personally I hate citronella more than mosquitos.

Comment: Nice and simple because of this new technique  its really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I know you said a net is difficult to build. I've seen bug nets that you can mount to a ceiling, like it's a central place where the net hangs from, and then it just drapes around the bed: [http://www.amazon.com/TC-NET-WHT-100-percent-Polyester-Mosquito-250mm/dp/B003AYVKAC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003AYVKAC)

(note I'm not recommending this particular product; I've never used it, this is just an example).

Comment: On a general note: Answers should be selfcontained if possible, here this means please inline images from a known/referred/cited/allowed source, and that there should be no need to follow external links to understand your answer. In your case, describe the shape and design and how it varies from the other solution.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @britanist's answer, I recommend this one. This shape and design helps you set this net by tying corners to distant objects using threads or ropes. It's more convenient.

Caution : Take care that no mosquito gets in while you are putting this net on. Else, you'll not be able to sleep even if there is electricity. :p

One nice way of doing that would be to place the mosquito net on the bed, wrapped. THen take each corner and tie it firmly to something. Make sure that no edge of the net loses contact with bed. Then, go inside and tuck it in.

[image]

#### This particular image is just an example. No recommendations for this particular product from this website or howsoever. I, personally, have used them for years without fail. Purchased one from local shops nearby.

Comment: Please be careful adding new answers which mostly favours another product. Product endorsement are not wanted on this site, but alternative solutions are in deed wanted.

Comment: Added. I only meant to show a square mosquito net.

Comment: On a general note: Answers should be selfcontained if possible, here this means please inline images from a known/referred/cited/allowed source, and that there should be no need to follow external links to understand your answer. In your case, describe the shape and design and how it varies from the other solution.

Comment: @holroy : Thanks man! Will keep in mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

You said you are unable to ward off mosquitos in times of power cuts and I suggest you get a rechargable table fan like [this](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/eveready-14-inch-rf03-rechargeable/279647380#bcrumbSearch:table%20fan) if you don't like the other options of mosquito nets and citronella.

[image]

Comment: I am really not sure about this. This may help but at the same time I also cant say if it is effective or not. There might be issues like where to put fan or if it will be productive (worth spending money on this fan or not).

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to sleep in a tent. Just get a tent big enough to fit your mattress inside if you don't want to use a sleeping bag.

This is very similar in essence to using a mosquito net, but more people already have tents lying around than have unused mosquito nets.

Answer (score 1):

We use very small mosquito tents that just cover our heads. I am including a picture here to demonstrate the form. In the photo the item appears to be one of those pop-up type items; the ones I have use two flexible and collapsible fiberglass rods.

Yes, this photo shows a sleeping bag but these are usable with standard bedding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As one of the other answers suggested, I just tested **lavender oil** on my arms and went to a heavily mosquito infested area and not one bite.  Works great:) They just flew right over my body, didn't land anywhere on it.